# How to switch an image on hover without disrupting its container(side-by-side layout)?

Tags: css

I've attached a demo of my existing code here:
https://codepen.io/codebat1/pen/QWzyQLw

I want two images to switch on hover but stay within the same grid. I've tried a few fade/in fade/out queries with pure CSS but its not working to be overlayed over the original image. I'd want something like main img->hover->switch->unhover->main img
Similar to [this](https://sirv.com/help/articles/hover-change-image/#:%7E:text=The%20best%20way%20to%20swap,and%20works%20on%20all%20browsers.). but I need to have my own JS function. Let me know if this can be done with pure CSS and if not how I could do it with JS.

```css
.blu {
    background: #3D5A6C;
    position: relative;
}

.box1{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #B287A3; 
    text-align: center;   
    justify-content: center;
}
.box1 h1 {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      margin-top: 175px;

}
.box2{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
      
.container {
    background: #3D5A6C;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5%;
    column-gap:20px;
}
      
.container box2, box1 {
    padding: 2%;
}

.home-pic{
    display:flex;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  .button {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #433A3F;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button span:after {
    content: '\2708';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}
.sev-won {
    text-decoration: none;

}
  div#line1 span#a {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  div#line1:hover span#a {
    display: none;
  }
  
  div#line1 span#b {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  div#line1:hover span#b {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
HTML CSSResult Skip Results Iframe
    <section class="blu">
        <div class="container reveal">
            <div class=" box1">
                <h1 class="revealsl fix">big test</h1>
                <p ></span></p> 
                <div class="revealsl fix buffer" id="line1">
                    <span id="a"><p>test</p></span><span id="b">A secret website easter egg!<br> </span>
                </div>
                <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>button </span></button>
            </div>
          <div class="box2">
            <div class="easter-egg">
                <img src="https://images.saymedia-content.com/.image/ar_1:1%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto:eco%2Cw_1200/MTk2NzY3MjA5ODc0MjY5ODI2/top-10-cutest-cat-photos-of-all-time.jpg" class="home-pic">
              </div>
          </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

When loading the image as

```
<img src="https://images.saymedia-content.com/.image/ar_1:1%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto:eco%2Cw_1200/MTk2NzY3MjA5ODc0MjY5ODI2/top-10-cutest-cat-photos-of-all-time.jpg" class="home-pic">
```

it doesn't easily function , you can try making the image a background image and change it on hover.

```
    /* Define the initial background image */
.hover-element {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('initial-image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background-image 0.3s ease; /* Add a smooth transition effect */
}

/* Change the background image on hover */
.hover-element:hover {
    background-image: url('hover-image.jpg');
}
```

or you can use javascript with onmouseover event listener like  this

```
// Get a reference to the element you want to change
const hoverElement = document.querySelector('.hover-element');

// Add a 'mouseover' event listener to change the background image on hover
hoverElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    hoverElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url("hover-image.jpg")';
});

// Add a 'mouseout' event listener to revert to the initial background image
hoverElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    hoverElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url("initial-image.jpg")';
});
```

Comment: for the JS would I add class="hover-element" to the appropriate container? I'm not quite sure what to add to the html